# Интеграция dahua anpr

Tags: python, python-3.x

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с интеграцией anpr камер dahua(или обычных). Нашел документацию от dahua(http api) . Есть вопрос. При получении номеров автомобиля с камеры, через определенное время(где-то 4 минуты), при отправке запросов начинает писать что неверный кэш сессии. Никак не могу понять почему так происходит. В доках по этому поводу тоже не нашел инфы.
Могу скинуть часть кода если это поможет.